# entityframework core handle isdeleted columns at global level

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2016

I have `is-deleted` column on all tables in sql db. I wanted to know if there is better way to handle `is-deleted` filter at global level instead of putting filter for `is-deleted` on each join in linq to sql while querying db using efcore.

I have joins with 5 to 8 entities and putting on each join doesn't look like good practice.

Is there a better pattern?

Comment: [EntityFramework-Plus global filters](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/EF-Query-Filter-%7C-Entity-Framework-Dynamic-Instance-and-Global-Filters) promises to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we were able to solve this problem using this nuget and some customizations
Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore

https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus